# Domain Driven Design - Creating general purpose entities vs. Context specific Entities

Tags: oop, entity, domain-driven-design, aggregate, aggregateroot

**Situation**

Suppose you have Orders and Clients as entities in your application. In one aggregate, the Order entity is considered to be the root but you also want to make use of the Client entity for simple things. In another the Client is the root entity and the Order entity is touched ever so lightly.

**An example:**

Let's say that in the Order aggregate I use the Client only to read details like name, address, build order history and not to make the client do client specific business logic. (like persistence, passwords resets and back flips..).

On the other hand, in the Client aggregate I use the Order entity to report on the client's buying habbits, order totals, order counting, without requiring advanced order functionality like order processing, updating, status changes, etc.

**Possible solution**

I believe the better solution is to create the entities for each aggregate specific to the aggregate context, because making them full featured (general purpose) and ready for any situation and usage seems like overkill and could potentially become a maintenance nightmare. (and potentially memory intensive)

**Question**

What is the DDD recommended way of handling this situation?
What is your take on the matter?

Comment: Both anwers make sense, but i can choose only one. So I flipped a coin. Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic driver for these decisions should be the ubiquitous language, and consequently the real world domain you're modeling. If both works in a specific domain, I'd **favor separation over god-classes for maintainability reasons**.

Apart from separating behavior into different aggregates, you should also take care that you **don't mix different bounded contexts**. Depending on the requirements of your domain, it could make sense to separate the *Purchase Context* from the *Reporting Context* (to extend on your example).

To decide on a context design, **context maps are a helpful tool**.

Answer (score 1):

You are one the right track. In DDD, entities are not merely containers encapsulating all attributes related to a "subject" (for example: a customer, or an order). This is a very important concept that eludes a lot of people. An entity in DDD represents an operation boundary, thus only the data necessary to perform the operation is considered to be a part of the entity. Exactly which data to include in an entity can be difficult to consider because some data is relevant in a different use-cases. Here are some tips when analyzing data:

- Analyze invariants, things that must be considered when applying validation rules and that can not be out of sync should be in the same aggregate.
- Drop the database-thinking, normalization is not a concern of DDD
- Just because things look the same, it doesn't mean that they are. For example: the current shipping address registered on a customer is different from the shipping address which a specific order was shipped to.
- Don't look at reads. Reading, like creating a report or populating av viewmodel/dto/whatever has nothing to do with operation boundaries and can typically be a 360 deg view of the data. In fact don't event use your domain model when returning reads, use a different architectural stack.